# What does $\sum_{1 \le j < k \le n}$ $Cov(X_j, X_k)$ denote?

Tags: summation

$Cov(X_j, X_k)$ notes the covariance of two random variables $X_j$ and $X_k$, but I don't think that it matters in this case. I just don't understand how to interpret the notation of the sum

$\sum_{1 \le j < k \le n}$ $Cov(X_j, X_k)$.

What summands does it possess?

Comment: If you prefer, you could write the sum as 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} Cov(X_j,X_k)
$$
maybe that's more familiar

Comment: So for $k = 1$, we would have $Cov(X_1, X_1) + Cov(X_2, X_1) + \ ...  \ + Cov(X_{k-1}, X_1)$?

Comment: For $k=1$, that would be an empty summation.  I should have written $\sum_{k=2}$.

Comment: Ah, indeed. :-)

Comment: Uh, wait, but my approach is wrong then, isn't it? For $k = 2$, I think we would have $Cov(X_1, X_2)$, and for $k = 3$, for example, $Cov(X_1 + X_2, X_3)$, right?

Comment: Your second statement is right. I don't see how that makes your approach wrong

Comment: Well, we don't have $Cov(X_1, X_3) + Cov(X_2, X_3) = Cov(X_1 + X_2, X_3)$, do we?

Comment: Yes we do, covariance is linear in each argument.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Thanks!